# SQL - Possible to Auto Increment Number but with leading zeros?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

Our IDs look something like this "CS0000001" which stands for Customer with the ID 1. Is this possible to to with SQL and Auto Increment or do i need to to that in my GUI ?

I need the leading zeroes but with auto incrementing to prevent double usage if am constructing the ID in Python and Insert them into the DB.

Is that possible?

Comment: I forget that generated column cannot refer to autoincremented field... answer deleted. Sorry...

Comment: No problem, do you habe any other idea how to do this?

Comment: Don't use cutomised ids for internal references.

Answer (score 1):

You have few choices:

1. Construct the CustomerID in your code which inserts the data into
   the Customer table (=application side, requires change in your code)
2. Create a view on top of the Customer-table that contains the logic
   and use that when you need the CustomerID (=database side, requires change in your code)
3. Use a procedure to do the inserts and construct the CustomerID in
   the procedure (=database side, requires change in your code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think i will create two Tables, Customer_ID and Customer_History, first for the IDs with auto increment and non leading zeroes. History for the Data an Data Versions. I will display the IDs in my GUI with zfill to give the user its known feeling of IDs. DO you see any problems with that approach?

Comment: If you only need the generated ID just for the user (you do not have other tables referencing to it), that would be a better option.

Comment: The good thing is we kind of start from scratch. So i could reference to the new ID. So its mainly for the user and documents. Prefix like CS for Customer and so on help humans a lot in some cases :-D

Answer (score 0):

Possible realization.

1. Create data table

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE data (id CHAR(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   >                    val TEXT,
   >                    PRIMARY KEY (id));
   > ```
2. Create service table

   > ```
   > CREATE TABLE ids (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
   > ```
3. Create trigger which generates `id` value

   > ```
   > CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_data
   > BEFORE INSERT
   > ON data
   > FOR EACH ROW
   > BEGIN
   >     INSERT INTO ids () VALUES ();
   >     SET NEW.id = CONCAT('CS', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 7, '0'));
   >     DELETE FROM ids;
   > END
   > ```
4. Create trigger which prohibits `id` value change

   > ```
   > CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_data
   > BEFORE UPDATE
   > ON data
   > FOR EACH ROW
   > BEGIN
   >     SET NEW.id = OLD.id;
   > END
   > ```
5. Insert some data, check result

   > ```
   > INSERT INTO data (val) VALUES ('data-1'), ('data-2');
   > SELECT * FROM data;
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > id        | val   
   > :-------- | :-----
   > CS0000001 | data-1
   > CS0000002 | data-2
   > ```
6. Try to update, ensure `id` change prohibited

   > ```
   > UPDATE data SET id = 'CS0000100' WHERE val = 'data-1';
   > SELECT * FROM data;
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > id        | val   
   > :-------- | :-----
   > CS0000001 | data-1
   > CS0000002 | data-2
   > ```
7. Insert one more data, ensure enumeration continues

   > ```
   > INSERT INTO data (val) VALUES ('data-3'), ('data-4');
   > SELECT * FROM data;
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > id        | val   
   > :-------- | :-----
   > CS0000001 | data-1
   > CS0000002 | data-2
   > CS0000003 | data-3
   > CS0000004 | data-4
   > ```
8. Check service table is successfully cleared

   > ```
   > SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ids;
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > | COUNT(*) |
   > | -------: |
   > |        0 |
   > ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac51d9b157995edb1a002cdd1fef959e)*

**Disadvantages:**

1. Additional table needed.
2. Generated `id` value edition is disabled (copy and delete old record must be used instead, custom value cannot be set).